# Hour of a Date using JPA and JPQL (in a NamedQuery)

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

In my table "creneau" I have a column "dateHeure". "dateHeure" is a date. I want to count the number of lines having "dateHeure" with an hour equal to a number I choose. I want to do the comparison directly in a NamedQuery.

I tried the code below but this one does not work :

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "compterCreneauxHeure", 
    query = "SELECT count(cre.creneauId) 
             FROM CreneauEntity cre 
             WHERE extract(HOUR cre.dateHeure) = :heure")
```

However, the one below works very well :

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "compterCreneauxHeure",
    query = "SELECT count(cre.creneauId) 
             FROM CreneauEntity cre 
             WHERE extract(DAY cre.dateHeure) = :heure")
```

(**:heure** is my number)

I do not understand where is my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL has no such function "extract", so you are seemingly relaying on your JPA provider supporting that. JPQL != SQL. Read a JPA reference document, or the JPA spec.

Most JPA providers would however support

```
SELECT count(cre.creneauId) FROM CreneauEntity cre WHERE HOUR(cre.dateHeure) = :heure
```

even though it is strictly speaking not part of the JPA spec (yet). Similarly most JPA providers would support a function `DAY(...)`. See https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/102

Comment: compilation error : "HOUR(cre.dateHeure) = :heure" -> The expression is not a valid conditional expression

Comment: so your JPA provider doesnt support it, but then you don't say what JPA provider.

Comment: Thanks for your help but, Would you have another solution that can be supported by my JPA Provider ?

Comment: You don't tell us what is your JPA Provider, so how could I ? since this is all JPA provider specific when it isn't covered by the JPA spec

Comment: Ok, I understand. Unfortunately I do not know what JPA Provider is used in my project. Anyway thank you for answering my question. You helped me a lot. I'll find another way to do what I need.